# Is there a way to figure out if a user installed an app on Google Play during pre-registration?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing

For those developers who implemented Pre-registration for their app, you can implement a special sku for their reward for signing up early. However, what if you don't want to roll out in-app billing?

What if you just wanted to have users pre-register your app with no in-app reward? How would one go about being able to make the distinction of those users who installed via pre-registration versus those who installed on or after launch day?

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 in-app products with two different prices and show the cheap one before a certain date and the normal price one after the date, but you will need an external server to get the date and avoid cheating by changing the date of the phone.

Comment: Thx but trying to avoid tying in Google Play Billing into the app given that there are no features that make use of it and I don't want to involve the server-side to make any changes so close to release which is coming up soon.

Comment: If you do not plan to use Google Play Billing I still understand less what you want to do and why you add the tags google-play, google-play-services and in-app-billing  ...

Comment: It's because some of the people/developers at Google check those tags. Pre-registration was originally built for incentivizing gamers with a free in-app purchase but not all apps on the Play Store are games. My use case is to incentivize users to pre-register and reward them IRL. A simple flag of identifying pre-registered users would have been helpful.